# Redux Action is Dispatched but state not updating accordingly

Tags: reactjs, redux

When i click the delete button the action(removeBus) is dispatched and the correct payload value is sent however the store is not updating
here is my busSlice file

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialState = [
  {
    id: "0",
    description: "bus1"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    description: "bus2"
  }
];
const busSlice = createSlice({
  name: "bus",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    removeBus: (state, action) => {
      state.filter((bus) => bus.id !== action.payload);
      console.log(action.payload);
    }
  }
});
export const { removeBus } = busSlice.actions;
export default busSlice.reducer;
```

here is where  i created and export the store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import busReducer from "../features/busSlice";
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    busses: busReducer
  }
});
```

the component that uses the state is created in the following code and App is wrapped inside a redux provider Component and the above store is provided as a props in index.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { removeBus } from "./features/busSlice";
export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const busses = useSelector((state) => state.busses);
  const handleRemove = (id) => {
    dispatch(removeBus(id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {busses.map((bus) => (
        <ul>
          <li key={bus.id}>
            <p>{bus.description}</p>
            <button onClick={() => handleRemove(bus.id)}>delete</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

using redux dev tools i can see an action busses\removeBus is dispatched with the appropriate payload value but nothing is happening to the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
removeBus: (state, action) => {
      state.filter((bus) => bus.id != action.payload);
      console.log(action.payload);
    }
```

can be the data types of **bus.id** and **action.payload** are different.

Comment: both bus.id and action.payload are strings and the correct payload value is shown in the console

Answer (score 0):

you are not updating state correctly you need to say change my state to filtered state

like this

```js
removeBus(state, action){
      state = state.filter((bus) => bus.id !== action.payload);
      console.log(action.payload);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: oh... ok but it was a bug anyway....

Comment: the problem maybe in your filtering logic I think

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue.

I my case, code looked like this:

```
const someSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'test',
  initialState: null, 
  reducers: {
  addData(state, action) {
     state = action.payload
   }
 } 
});
```

This did not work

```
const someSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'test',
  initialState: null, 
  reducers: {
  addData(state, action) {
     state = action.payload;
     return state;
   }
 } 
});
```

this worked.

But this is very strange, should not work this way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your updated states

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialState = [
  {
    id: "0",
    description: "bus1"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    description: "bus2"
  }
];
const busSlice = createSlice({
  name: "bus",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    removeBus: (state, action) => {
      state = state.filter((bus) => bus.id !== action.payload);
      return state;
    }
  }
});
export const { removeBus } = busSlice.actions;
export default busSlice.reducer;
```